# How to assign labels and color code to data manually in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, legend, scatter-plot

I've three 1-D arrays,

```
BT1=np.random.uniform(180,300,size=[1,100]) #x
BT2=np.random.uniform(180,300,size=[1,100]) #y
color_code=np.random.choice(0,1,size-[1,100]) #color code

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
scatter=ax.scatter(BT1,BT2,c=color_code)
ax.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels=["Clear","Cloudy"], title="Cloud Mask")
ax.set_xlabel("TIR1 sample BT")
ax.set_ylabel("TIR2 sample BT")
```

Array `color_code` contains 0,1 which is used for color coding the scatter plot.

I need `0` in array to be assigned label `"Clear"` and `1` to be assigned label `"Cloudy"`.

Basically, I need `"0,Clear"` and `"1,Cloudy"` as the correct label to appear against color `Blue` and `Red` respectively.

Problem:- The labels passed to the scatter are `["Clear","Cloudy"]`. So `matplotlib` assigns the first occurring element in `color_code` the label `"Clear"` and the 2nd element the label `"Cloudy"`.

So, if `color_code=Array(1,0,0,1.....)`, `1` would be assigned the label `Clear` even though it's wrong.

I've tried the method below but it didn't work

```
leg = ax.get_legend()
hl_dict = {handle.get_label(): handle for handle in leg.legendHandles}
hl_dict['0'].set_color('blue')
hl_dict['1'].set_color('red')
```

How can I add the link the label to the data correctly?

Comment: By far the easiest way, is to use Seaborn's scatter plot, e.g. `sns.scatterplot(x=BT1, y=BT2, hue=pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes=color_code, categories=['Clear', 'Cloudy'], ordered=True))`.  Instead of `pd.Categorical.from_codes` you could also directly provide a list of strings. Note that `BT1`,  `BT2` and `color_code` should be one-dimensional (so `size=100` instead of `size=[1,00]`.

Comment: @JohanC I tried this one, it works. Props to you for the answer. Why exactly ```seaborn.scatterplot``` works while ```plt.scatter``` does not?

Comment: @JohanC I want to set the color ```red``` for ```"Cloudy"``` and ```green``` for ```"Clear"```. The ```palette``` method isn't working together with ```Categorical.from_codes()```. It throws an error ```Categorical.from_codes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'palette'```

Comment: Well, you need to add the `palette=` parameter to `sns.scatterplot(...., palette={'Clear':'green', 'Cloudy':'red'})`, not to `pd.Categorical.from_codes(....)`.

Comment: `sns.scatterplot(...)` is a much more high-level function, build on `plt.scatter(...)`.

Comment: @JohanC I seem to be stuck. I put the color code against "0"/"1" and "Clear"/"Cloudy", one at a time,  but they didn't work. This is the code I'm using currently ```sns.scatterplot(ax=ax,
 x=BT1,
 y=BT2, 
 hue=color_code,
 palette={"Cloudy":'green', "Clear":'red'},
 categories=['Clear', 'Cloudy'],
 ordered=True)``` . The error is ```The palette dictionary is missing keys: {0, 1}```

Comment: Did you try `sns.scatterplot(x=BT1, y=BT2, hue=pd.Categorical.from_codes(codes=color_code, categories=['Clear', 'Cloudy'], ordered=True), palette={"Cloudy":'green', "Clear":'red'})`?

Comment: @JohanC Yes, I did. Something weird is happening.  It's compiling but now showing anything, even after the command ```plt.show()```.

Comment: Are you running the latest seaborn version?  Did you try to restart your environment?

Comment: @JohanC Yes, latest version ```0.12.1```. Restarted the environment, did a correction, it worked. I was passing an axis in the ```ax=```(first declare an axis with ```subplots```,then pass here) argument inside the ```scatterplot```. It's working now with proper labels and colors. Thank you for your help. Seems like I can't pass an axis for now but I'll work it out.